# No title option in moderncv leaving horizontal line beside name?

Tags: moderncv

Basically using the no title option and the `banking` theme in `moderncv` leaves me with a horizontal line beside the name. It used to remove the line but a recent update changed something which I am not too sure about. Using the standard `template.tex` from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples and commenting the following line:

```
\title{Resum√© title}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
```

leaves me with something that looks like this:

[image]

Note that I am using TeXLive and TeXshop. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: The bug has been fixed and the class on CTAN been updated, voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug to me, possibly just a typo in the document class. I boiled the template down to a MWE and the bar remains:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking} 
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I'd assume the author of `moderncv`, [Xavier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10102/xavier), will come across this question within the next few days. If he doesn't, you can [file a bug report](https://launchpad.net/moderncv) yourself.

Comment: Definitely a bug; thanks for reporting! I just submitted a fix to ctan, so it should hit TeX distributions in a few days. If you're in a hurry Jeremy, locate and open `moderncvstylebanking.sty` and replace line 92 by this: `\ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}\\%`

Comment: @Xavier This worked for me like a charm. I'm using the template on overleaf.com which must not be updated, seeing as this post is 3 years old.